# WSO2 ESB Web destroys nice synapse XML structure

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

We developed our proxies, sequences and so on with a XML editor and had a very good structure of the synapse configurations, but as we open the component with the web interface and the whole code is realigned and changed.

Is there a way to see the content of the components with the web **without destroying the whole structure**?

This here was our code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="patient_toMPI_pJMS_qToMPIXml" statistics="disable" trace="disable" transports="jms">
<parameter name="transport.jms.Destination">queueName</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactory">queueBlocking</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.jms.DestinationType">queue</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.jms.ContentType">
    <rules>
        <jmsProperty>contentType</jmsProperty>
        <default>application/xml</default>
    </rules>
</parameter>
<target faultSequence="rollbackSequence">
    <inSequence>
        <property name="frameworkContext" expression="get-property('default', 'frameworkContext')" scope="transport"/>
        <property name="frameworkMessageId" expression="get-property('default', 'frameworkMessageId')" scope="transport"/>
        <property name="frameworkTransactionId" expression="get-property('default', 'frameworkTransactionId')" scope="transport"/>          
    </inSequence>
</target>
```

After opening just once with the web interface it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
   name="patient_toMPI_pJMS_qToMPIXml"
   transports="jms"
   startOnLoad="true"
   trace="disable">
<target faultSequence="rollbackSequence">
  <inSequence>
     <property xmlns:urn="urn:hl7-org:v2xml"
               xmlns:hl7="http://wso2.org/hl7"
               name="frameworkContext"
               expression="get-property('default', 'frameworkContext')"
               scope="transport"/>
     <property xmlns:urn="urn:hl7-org:v2xml"
               xmlns:hl7="http://wso2.org/hl7"
               name="frameworkMessageId"
               expression="get-property('default', 'frameworkMessageId')"
               scope="transport"/>
     <property xmlns:urn="urn:hl7-org:v2xml"
               xmlns:hl7="http://wso2.org/hl7"
               name="frameworkTransactionId"
               expression="get-property('default', 'frameworkTransactionId')"
               scope="transport"/>         
  </inSequence>
</target>
<parameter name="transport.jms.ContentType">
  <rules>
     <jmsProperty>contentType</jmsProperty>
     <default>application/xml</default>
  </rules>
</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactory">queueBlocking</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.jms.DestinationType">queue</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.jms.Destination">queueName</parameter>
</proxy>
```

Is this a bug within WSO2? Is it configurable?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see much change done in your configuration. Properties are pushed down to the bottom (thats the only change I see) and thats the normal behaviour in WSO2 ESB.

There is no way to view the source without using the web console (unless you view it from the file system).

Comment: Well the problem (sorry forgot to mention) is that our proxies are stored on a SVN and each time we open a component in the web-gui it changes the structure and our SVN recognizes a change - but in fact there was none. Should we continue with the style from the web-gui?

Comment: Yes. Its ok to continue with that style.